# Watir does not work with Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

I upgraded Ruby to 1.9.3, and watir stopped working. Did anyone experience the same issue?

**Update** watir has a dependency on ffi, just need to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Ruby193\bin>gem list watir
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
watir (2.0.4)

C:\Ruby193\bin>irb

irb(main):001:0> require "watir"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/windows-api-0.4.0/lib/windows/api.rb:4: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
=> #<Watir::IE:0x..f867b09ec url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0>
```