# new window creation in watir

Tags: ruby, browser, new-operator, watir

I am new to watir. I am trying to create new ie window with

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

but it gives error message like

```
`user_is_bewildered': Error in the default values: :browser's value must be one of 'ie', 'firefox', or 'safari', and '' doesn't look right. (StandardError)
```

I donno how to set default browser. Can some one help me? There is a another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337338/watir-does-not-work-with-ruby-1-9-3). But I am not able to understand what i need to do in ffi.

Thanks

Comment: What OS? What version of Ruby? What version of the watir gem?

Comment: You should identify what errors occurred when you installed the gem. I imagine that ffi is a gem that installs with watir (it installed with my watir-webdriver). If you do not have the devkit installed and configured, you will have problems installing correctly, then it won't run correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the original Watir gem, then the following is how I used to launch it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
browser = Watir::Browser.new

# Whatever you want to do in watir
```

IamChuckB's answer may be a more efficient way of doing this, but having not used it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell it which browser to open. Try this:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
```

I haven't played around with watir since my last job so I had to look this up. As I last recall, WATIR was not entirely integrated with FireWATIR (the Firefox based variant). It's good to see that the two have apparently been reconciled in the meantime.

Taken from [Watir in Five Minutes](https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/watir-in-five-minutes.md) on Zeljko Filipin's github, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

To install devkit,

1. create a folder in the ruby directory called devkit
2. get the devkit from [here](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe)
3. unpack it into the devkit directory created in step 1
4. add **c:\ruby193\devkit\bin;c:\ruby193\devkit\wming\bin** to your path, of course adjusting for your ruby install directory

now open a command prompt to install the gem again

```
c:\> gem install watir
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Thanx for the the inputs. The issue was with wrong nokorigi gem installation, initially i installed x86-mswin32-60, i uninstalled it and tried with x86-mingw32, it solved.